# HP Wireless Mouse doesnt work if not moved during Win10 x64 startup

Tags: windows-10, wireless-mouse

HP Desktop PC with Win10x64 came with a HP wireless keyboard & HP mouse HSA-D01M running off a USB dongle. If the mouse isn't moved (and sometimes even if it is moved) during startup, it doesn't work. However, the keyboard working off the same dongle works fine. Occasionally, the mouse also went dead when the computer was idle for some time. I've tried removing the battery, spinning the battery to clear any contact issues … it often doesn't help. When it does start working, it works perfectly, so the battery is probably be ok (it's a Duracell, less than 6 months old, used ~9hours/day). There's no reset button on the mouse, the dongle is hard to reach at the back of the PC.
Is there a "software" way to wake the mouse ?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the wireless mouse and delete driver from Device Manager.

Change another USB port for dongle.

In Device Manager, untick Allow the computer to turn off the device to save power option on your mouse’s Power Management tab.

In general, before a wireless mouse works, we need to click the left mouse button.

Similar case here:

How do you fix an HP wireless mouse that is not working?

https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-fix-an-HP-wireless-mouse-that-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

If the signal between the mouse and its usb dongle is lost: 1. Take the usb dongle оut of your computer. 2. Turn off the mouse on/off switch. 3. While holding down simultaneously the right and middle mouse buttons, turn on the mouse, and release the buttons 5 seconds after turning on the mouse. 4. Within 5 seconds, plug the USB dongle into the computer's USB port. The mouse and usb dongle should be paired.